# How do I change the ACLs on a registry key? (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, permissions, registry

I need to delete a regsitry key. It has a deny ACL on Set Value (I need this permission to delete it).

How do I change the ACLs in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use RegSetKeySecurity to adjust the security settings and then delete the key as usual.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Win32 FAQ.

See Win32 api ng news://194.177.96.26/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32